# Header Styling Not Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm doing Facebook Ads for a client. I only know basic HTML & CSS, enough to at least play around.

The problem is the website header section (the black background around the logo and header menus) isn't responsive and cuts off at around 950px width and gets worse the closer you get towards a mobile viewport. The website is below.

http://www.vibrantrealestate.com.au/

I've got access to WordPress and FTP so I'd really appreciate some guidance on what HTML/CSS I'd have to adjust.

Thanks Heaps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/style.css line number 92`

```
#main-wrap {
    float: left;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 100%;
}
```

Just comment that `width: 100%`